# Conjunction attributes in Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to build a query in [overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) in order to find all cathedrals with specific characteristics such as

*amenity=place_of_worship,religion=catholic,denomination=St. Mary etc.*

How could i combine all these attributes into this simple query provided by overpass turbo

```
node
  [amenity=drinking_water]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

Additionally i have found this [osm map feature](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) guide for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the overpass turbo wizard, enter "amenity=place_of_worship and religion=catholic" and it will generate the following query:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“amenity=place_of_worship and religion=catholic”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=place_of_worship and religion=catholic”
  node["amenity"="place_of_worship"]["religion"="catholic"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="place_of_worship"]["religion"="catholic"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="place_of_worship"]["religion"="catholic"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Also see the [Overpass API Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide).